# Probability of quadratic real solutions

Tags: pr.probability, polynomials, binary-quadratic-forms

Solving geometric equations that sometimes lead to complex solutions made me
wonder how commonly this occurs.

I have two quadratic polynomial equations in $x$ and $y$,
$$a\, x^2 + b\, x y + c\, y^2 + d\, x + e\, y + f = 0 \;$$
$$a' x^2 + b' x y + c' y^2 + d' x + e' y + f' = 0 \;$$
where $a,b,c,d,e,f,a',b',c',d',e',f'$ are each uniformly random within $[-1,1]$.

> ***Q***. What is the probability that the pair of equations has at least one real solution?

Typically there are four $(x,y)$ solutions, with an even number of real solutions.
Simulations show that the probability is about $0.679$ (in $10^5$ trials),
but I would appreciate learning how to formally calculate this probability.

Comment: Start by using Reduce in Mathematica, as here: https://mathoverflow.net/a/385763/44143 After that it should be an easy enough integration.

Comment: My previous comment was for existence of real solutions to a single quadratic...even then I now see the integral would have been messy. Two equations would give a 12-dimensional integral of a region where some quadratic inequalities hold, and that’s likely too messy for closed-form integration.